# how to post data with ajax, php and bootstrap select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am banging my head against a wall with this now so any help will go a long way with this one.

I am trying to get some data from a drop down list and update a database with the data selected.

This is my drop down list:

```
<form method="post" data-remote="true">
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="status[]">
    <?php while($test3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($test2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
        <option data-tokens="<?php echo $test3['Name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $test3['Name']; ?>"> 
        </option 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
```

View Area

This is my ajax:

```
        $(document).on('click', '#sim-area', function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'sim-area.php',
            data: {changeStatus: status},
            success: function() {
              "area switched"
            }
          });
        });
```

and this is my page that is updating the databse (sim-area.php):

```
<?php

$userID = $user['userID'];
$selectedArea = $_GET['changeStatus'];
$queryAreaName = "
        SELECT UserID, Name, U_NB, U_RTN
        FROM Table
        WHERE UserID = '$userID' AND Name = '$selectedArea'";
$getAreaname = sqlsrv_query($sapconn2, $queryAreaName);
$areaSwitch = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getAreaname, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

$areaNB = $test2['U_NB'];
$areaRTN = $test2['U_RTN'];

//UPDATE TABLE

?>
```

No matter what I try I get an undefined error, I have changed it to hard code the values and in inserts fine, so I know everything is working fine, It just isn't passing the data through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks you are not passing data correctly to ajax call.
Below is updated code for dropdown (changed `name` of select and added `id` attribute):

```
    <form method="post" data-remote="true">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="status" id="changeStatus">
        <?php while($test3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($test2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
            <option data-tokens="<?php echo $test3['Name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $test3['Name']; ?>"> 
            </option 
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
```

Updated code for jquery (changed code for passing value of `data`):

```
    $(document).on('click', '#sim-area', function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'sim-area.php',
        data: {changeStatus: $('#changeStatus').val()},
        success: function() {
          "area switched"
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, but i am still getting the same error : Notice: Undefined index: changeStatus

Comment: sorry my bad your code worked perfectly it was an error on my part not changing a variable name.